# Angular Memory Leak Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find Memory leak in Angular 7 application, for that 
I was comparing 2 snapshots and notice that there is a component (`GridBuilderComponent`) getting called 4 times and also get destroyed (notice `ngOnDestroy` getting executed).

But on Memory snapshot comparison window, I can see that value for **#New** column is **4** and value for **#Deleted** column is **0** as below, [image]

I have tried to nullify most of the properties in `ngOnDestroy` on that component, but still the **Allocation Size** remains the same.  i.e. `272`
[image]

So my question why reference of GridBuilderComponent still alive after it's destroy get called? even after nullified all properties and unsubscribe from service references.
Any pointers will be helpful.

**One this that I have tried is deleting the properties of component**, like this:
`Object.keys(this).forEach(item => {
      delete this[item];
    });`

Although this does not remove the component from memory, it does help to decrease the **Allocation Size** the component took on memory from `272` to `24`, see this snapshot:[image]

Comment: Is this component being alive with an `ngIf` ? Ie: `<custom-component *ngIf="somethingThatIsTrueOrFalse"></custom-component>` ?

Comment: Yes, in few cases, but when I have taken 2nd snapshot that component and also parent component also destroyed.

Comment: If you just clear up all the logic inside those components, the problem still persist when they get destroyed?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi , Yes once I remove all codes inside the component , I cannot see any more reference of the component in snapshot. what I need to do to remove the reference of the component.

Comment: I'm just guessing, maybe the subscription are keeped alive. Are you using the `takeWhile` operator?

Comment: Not takeWhile, but I am unsubscribeing from service reference in destroy method.

Comment: @Posto, I faced with the same issue, but I don't want to delete all properties on destroying (it's an angular responsibility). Did you solve it or still using this workaround?